# Converting Exception from WebService to get specific error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, exception

I have a problem with WebServises exception hendeling.
When webservice throw an exception it fals in catch(exception e) block

But it convetr exception class to WsAppExcepotion and insert information about error in Detail.ErrorString

[What exception i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4NaY.jpg)

But in class exception there is no propoty like Detail 
so i can't jest return e.Detail.ErrorString

I tried to create my ownexception like this

```
public class WsException : Exception
{
    public WsDetail Detail { get; set; }

    public class WsDetail 
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string InnerExceptionMessage { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string StackTrace { get; set; }
        public string Target { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But it's just stop catching exception

```
catch (WsExseption e)
```

i also tried like this

```
public static void LogMeaningfulMessage(Exception e, string serviceName, string state)
    {
        var ed = e as FaultException<dynamic>;
        if (ed != null)
        {
            Log.Error("Call to {0} for {1}, error: {2}", serviceName, state, ed.Detail.errorString);
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                LogMeaningfulMessage(e.InnerException, serviceName, state);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Error("Call to {0} for {1}, error: {2}", serviceName, state, e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

But on like  var ed = e as FaultException
ed will be null...

Maybe i'm doing it wrong?
or there is other method to get this ErrorString from Detail?

And i also tried to serialize it in Json and back in model WsException.. didn't work for me...

Comment: have you tried this approach which is mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649840.aspx)

Comment: You need to inherit the base class Exception and override all its method with your own data and behavior , in this way you can form a customized error page